# How to generate a coordinate file for a specific dependency in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, smbj

I am trying to generates the coordinate file for my project. The directory structure of my project is as follow.

[image]

My build.gradle contains "compile 'com.hierynomus:smbj:0.9.0'" dependency.
I have navigated to the 'sourceDir' path and I am trying the following command to generate the coordinates file:

```
.\gradlew.bat getDependenciesCoordinates --coordinate com.hierynomus:smbj:0.9.0
```

**After running this command I am getting the following error:**

- What went wrong:
  [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Problem configuring task :getDependenciesCoordinates from command line.
  [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unknown command-line option '--coordinate'.

Can any one help me with this issue ?

Comment: Also, I forgot to add that when I try $ ./gradlew.bat help --task :getDependenciesCoordinates i don't see any option for the parameter

Comment: If I use $ ./gradlew.bat getDependenciesCoordinates com.hierynomus:smbj:0.9.0 then I am getting 'com.hierynumous' not found in root path 'SourceDirectory'

Comment: I tried to look up what task `getDependenciesCoordinates` is, but I got no results. Can you point me to the documentation of that task to understand what it does?

Comment: I was suggested to use getDependenciesCoordinates by one of my friend. I will ask him and get back to you on this one.